# Dictionary in python not being modified in the global scope

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my test code:

```
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {"sui": "haiyaa"}
def bruh(dictionary1, dictionary2):
    dictionary1 = {"sup":"mgoi", "bruh":"moment"}
    dictionary2.update({"sup":"mgoi", "bruh":"moment"})
    print(dictionary1)
    print(dictionary2)
    
bruh(dict1, dict2)
print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

The output is this:

```
{'sup': 'mgoi', 'bruh': 'moment'}
{'sui': 'haiyaa', 'sup': 'mgoi', 'bruh': 'moment'}
{}
{'sui': 'haiyaa', 'sup': 'mgoi', 'bruh': 'moment'}
```

Why is dict1 not being modified after making changes inside the function? For some reason, if I use update to make a change it does get modified in the global scope but not otherwise. Thank you so much.

Comment: `dictionary1=...` overshadows the argument `dictionary1`. Its scope is limited to your function. Use [dictionary methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp) to modify the dicts you have passed references to. (like you did with `update`)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tranbi commented, in your `bruh` function you are making an ***assignment*** to dictionary1 by using the = operator:

```
dictionary1 = {"sup":"mgoi", "bruh":"moment"}
```

This has now made it a local variable to the `bruh` function (its scope is for that function only) and has nothing to do with `dict1` any more. i.e. You have replaced (overwritten the variable `dictionary1` passed in as an argument) the reference to your `dict1` object with a local dictionary which will expire when the `bruh` function ends.

The `update` method on `dictionary2` works on your global `dict2` because you're actually calling the method on the ***instance*** of `dict2`. (Because `dictionary2` in your function is still a reference to that object.)

You can see this in action by adding this line:

```
dictionary2 = {"foo": "bar"}
```

above your `update` in your `bruh` function. Running the code then will produce this output:

```
{'sup': 'mgoi', 'bruh': 'moment'}
{'foo': 'bar', 'sup': 'mgoi', 'bruh': 'moment'}
{}
{'sui': 'haiyaa'}
```

As you can see, we have now also done the same to `dictionary2` in making it a local variable scoped only to the `bruh` function (overwriting the reference to `dict2` -- identified as `dictionary2` -- passed in as an argument). The `update` on it now updates the local `dict` within that function. When the function ends, the global `dict2` remains unchanged. Because, like `dict1` now, you are not actually referencing them at all in your function. You are instead working on local scope (because we have reassigned `dictionary1` and `dictionary2` to be local dictionaries within our function, overwriting the two values passed in to the function -- actually making them irrelevant).

So as @Tranbi said, if you want to work on global dictionaries in this way in functions, you should use `dict` methods (more info here: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)) on them, and do not overwrite their references with new assignments.

You can also use statements like this within your function which will have your desired effect in this scenario:

```
dictionary1["sup"] = "mgoi"
```